# Android Kotlin Socket.IO - Callback not invoked in future function

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, socket.io

I'm working on a Android Kotlin project where I'm using Socket.IO to communicate with a Nodejs backend. I have a function request that emits an event to the server and expects a callback with data in response. However, I'm facing an issue where the callback is not being invoked in the request function, while it works when I emit the event with a callback directly.

My main goal is to receive Ack callback and assign it to variable without using coroutines

Here's my Kotlin code:

```
lateinit var socket: Socket

fun startMic() {
    val opts = IO.Options()
    opts.path = "/mic-io"
    opts.query = ""
    opts.forceNew = true
    opts.reconnection = true
    socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.3:9600", opts)
    if (!socket.connected()) {
        Log.i("MICTAG", "CONNECTING")
        socket.connect()
    }

    socket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
        Log.i("MICTAG", "CONNECTED")
        val res = request("getRtpCapabilities")
        Log.i("MICTAG", "DONE")
    }
}

fun request(event: String): Array<Any?>? {
    val future = CompletableFuture<Array<Any?>?>()
    Log.i("MICTAG", "SENDING")
    socket.emit(event, Ack { data: Array<Any?>? ->
       
        ////// NEVER GET IN HERE //////

        Log.i("MICTAG","new data using future")
        future.complete(data)
    })

    return future.join()
}
```

The output:

```
- CONNECTING
- CONNECTED
- SENDING
```

When I call request, the callback provided in the request function is not invoked. However, when I directly emit the event with a callback as shown below, it works:

```
socket.emit("getRtpCapabilities", Ack { data: Array<Any?>? ->
    msg("new data using callback")
})
```

On the Node.js server, I have a corresponding event handler:

```
socket.on('getRtpCapabilities', (callback) => {
    console.log('new data');
    callback({ ok: 'success' });
});
```